# CD reporting placeholder was not found in the "Home" item

Tags: content-editor, placeholders

Sitecore 8.2 Update 3

There were a lot of broken links so I used the admin tool to remove them, but I am still getting tons of "placeholder was not found in the 'Home' item" messages in the log. I removed the broken links on both the web and master databases. I then restarted the website in IIS on CDs, but I am still getting the message. Additionally, I rescanned the databases after removing and the broken links are gone now.

Here are some of the log entries I am seeing; how do I fix this?

> 1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column#right_24e08ba4-8240-44a7-b5ed-dfdc036ef8e3" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_83757179-ba94-4ec5-a737-665136ddd2be/whoweserve" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_83757179-ba94-4ec5-a737-665136ddd2be/whoweserve" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_83757179-ba94-4ec5-a737-665136ddd2be/whoweserve" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_83757179-ba94-4ec5-a737-665136ddd2be" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column#right_fa743b2c-84bb-420e-922c-dc200b4c9b4c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column#middle_fa743b2c-84bb-420e-922c-dc200b4c9b4c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column#left_fa743b2c-84bb-420e-922c-dc200b4c9b4c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_3b84c3da-bdfa-497e-b69e-3bb6c8dab926/relatedcontent" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_3b84c3da-bdfa-497e-b69e-3bb6c8dab926/relatedcontent" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_3b84c3da-bdfa-497e-b69e-3bb6c8dab926/relatedcontent" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_3b84c3da-bdfa-497e-b69e-3bb6c8dab926/relatedcontent" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_3b84c3da-bdfa-497e-b69e-3bb6c8dab926/relatedcontent" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "content" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/herocontent/carousel" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/herocontent/carousel" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).
>   1132 12:18:05 WARN  The "/content/grid_8c12595e-53d4-472f-9320-3176237de78c/column_9d29d7a7-2340-481a-9a16-eb470fb94e4e" placeholder was not found in the "Home" item ({44D7B423-5530-4B5D-A0AE-3F80D9B1BC4B}).

Comment: did you upgrade the Sitecore version?

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to Sitecore 9?

Comment: Sorry! I am on 8.2 update 3. I have not updated Sitecore recently.

Comment: do these warnings impact any Sitecore functionality? second, can you disable the cache and check if these warnings are still logging, make sure to clear the cache?

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple possible causes for this kind of warning in log -

- Rendering markup was taken from HTML cache, thus no rendering process took place, you can safely ignore the diagnostic message in this case​.
- Rendering markup was not rendered due to no parent placeholder was found – item rendering settings should be checked, for this.

Most of the time is related to HTML cache but if you don't want to ignore, You can control the message by using `Rendering.TraceUnusedRenderings` setting in config. To mute this message you need to add below setting in the patch config and set the value to false -

```
    <setting name="Rendering.TraceUnusedRenderings" value="false" />
```

**How does it work**? When the page renders, Sitecore checks whether placeholder tags (related to that page) are present on the page or not. On the first request, it doesn't check for the cache and render it without any warning because it found the placeholder tag. It also stores the result HTML markup of the page in cache if your website is configured to use HTML cache.

Now on second and subsequent requests its first checks in the Cache and found the HTML in it but not able to find the placeholder tag because HTML don't have a placeholder tag, so it logs this as a warning. A method in Sitecore.kernel -  `Sitecore.Layouts.PageContext.TraceUnusedRendering` control all these logging and its control by `Rendering.TraceUnusedRenderings` setting. the default value of this setting is true so if you don't found this in config feel free to add it.

**Update** - 
As per your comments, it looks like adding the above setting is not working for you and since it does not impact any Sitecore functionality except writing a huge number of these warnings to log files. you can simply add a filter in your  log4net configuration, it will prevent the log file size increasing due to these huge numbers of warnings. see below configuration -

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging"> 
   <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt" />     
   <appendToFile value="true" />     
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />     
   </layout>     
   <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
      <stringToMatch value="placeholder was not found in the"/>
      <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
   </filter>     
   <encoding value="utf-8" />     
</appender>
```

If you think this is not a solution(I personally think the same) then I will suggest you reach out to the Sitecore Support.

Comment: What concerned me most is that I thought this was a new development. But I see now that it's been going on since 2017. I have no idea why I haven't noticed them before.

Comment: I did add the setting, but it does not seem to have had any effect. The file is inside a folder inside the "Include" folder. I searched all config files and the setting is in no other config file.I also tried placing it directly in the Sitecore.config file.

Comment: Thank you, that did remove the errors. As you said, it's not really a solution to the problem, but it works for my circumstance. Unfortunately, we are outside of support (8.2 is no longer supported). I really appreciate the efforts of people like you who reach out and try to help; thank you.